# jQuery DataTables - Remove from and splice data from array

Tags: jquery, arrays, datatable, datatables

I'm trying to remove records from a list of items and its array of data when selected rows are deleted.

I can remove the rows from the table and redraw it, but when I log out the table's data to the console, it still contains the objects that were deleted, and the documentation doesn't seem to have anything about splicing selected row data, only row indexes specified manually in jquery.

**Table initialisation**

```
var itemsTable = $('table#invoiceItemsTable').DataTable({
    data: invoiceItems,
    responsive: true,
    order: [],
    columns: [{
            data: 'Description',
            title: 'Description',
            width: '25%',
            className: 'dt-head-left dt-body-left'
        },
        {
            data: 'NominalId',
            title: 'Nominal Code',
            width: '15%',
            className: 'dt-left'
        },
        {
            data: 'Quantity',
            render: function(data) {
                return $.addCommas(data).replace('.00', '');
            },
            title: 'Quantity',
            width: '10%',
            className: 'dt-right'
        },
        {
            data: 'UnitPrice.BaseValue',
            render: function(data) {
                return '£' + $.addCommas(data);
            },
            title: 'Unit Price',
            width: '10%',
            className: 'dt-right'
        },
        {
            data: 'TaxCodeName',
            title: 'Tax Code',
            width: '15%',
            className: 'dt-head-left dt-body-left'
        },
        {
            data: 'Tax.BaseValue',
            render: function(data) {
                return '£' + $.addCommas(data);
            },
            title: 'Tax',
            width: '10%',
            className: 'dt-right'
        },
        {
            data: 'Subtotal.BaseValue',
            render: function(data) {
                return '£' + $.addCommas(data);
            },
            title: 'Subtotal',
            width: '15%',
            className: 'dt-right'
        }
    ]
})
```

**Handler for row deletion**

```
$('#deleteInvoiceItems').on('click', function() {
    console.log('----------------------------');

    var selectedRows = itemsTable.rows('.selected').indexes();
    console.log('Selected rows:');
    console.log(selectedRows);

    var data = itemsTable.data();

    itemsTable.rows(selectedRows).remove().draw();

    console.log('itemsTable.data(): ' );
    console.log(data);

    $(this).hide();

    if (!invoiceItems.length) {
        $('#saveInvoice').hide();
    }

    console.log('invoiceItems');
    console.log(invoiceItems);

    calcInvoiceTotals();
})
```

Comment: Indeed strange,your code will actually remove the selected rows.BTW which version of datatable is it?Could you create a plnkr?

Comment: Could you try with `itemsTable.row('.selected').remove().draw();`

Comment: I've just tried that and it doesn't make a difference. I've made a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/s3o7tc4x/.

Comment: Datatables keeps its data in its own data structures.  Datatables is not going to update your `invoiceItems` array.  That is something you will need to do if its needed.  Alternatively if you want to get a current array from Datatables you can use something like this: `itemsTable.rows().data().toArray()`.  Reference the [toArray()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/toArray()) docs.

Comment: Okay, that's not the main problem I'm having. The main issue here is that the data doesn't update with records deleted when they're removed via the remove() method from the table.

Comment: Guess I'm confused.  When you say "the data doesn't update" are you referring to the variable `invoiceItems`?  I forked your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qq34qdwj/1/) and added a console.log output, just below yours, showing the data that remains in the table after removal.  From a Datatables standpoint everything is working.  Even though you used `invoiceItems` to load the data into Datatables it has no knowledge of the variable to update it.

Comment: By the data, I mean where I've stored the table data in a variable called data - var data = itemsTable.data();. So the actual table data, not the array that is given to the table when it's initialised. When items are removed from the table, the table's data is not updated with records removed. The invoiceItems array as you can see from the script above, is only used to initialise the table.

Comment: I've just tested the fiddle you adjusted and it seems to be working. Looks like the thing that did it was getting the table data via .rows().data().toArray, which returns only the remaining items in the table. Strange that using only .data() to return the table data was giving the array including the deleted items earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Logging out the data with `itemsTable.rows().data().toArray()` looks like the correct way to get the remaining table data after items are removed, as suggested by K Thorngren.

Using only `itemsTable.data()` returns all items including those deleted, even after they are no longer present in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You need redraw the table with the array.

```
var table= $([ SELECTOR FOR YOUR TABLE]).DataTable()
var table= $([ SELECTOR FOR YOUR TABLE]).dataTable() /* ONLY FOR LEGACY DATATABLES */

table.clear().draw();
table.rows.add(array);
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

That should solve you question.